# Want to implement jquery-ui-daterangepicker in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi Friend I want to use jquery ui datepicker plugin in my app 
I am using http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ this plugin and want same functionality without any change
I have tried something like this code below

```
(function(){
angular.module('publisher-portal').directive('dateRangePicker', function () {
    return {
         restrict : 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link : function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            element.daterangepicker();
         }
    };
});
})();
<input id="e2" type="text" ng-model="mydate" dateRangePicker/>
```

Please suggest me some solution

Comment: did you consider to use https://github.com/fragaria/angular-daterangepicker

Comment: Yes but I want same interface like http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ this plugin

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/ is this fine by you?

Comment: I already searched for all plugin of angular and jquery but http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/ this is best suited Please help me to implement that plug in

Comment: what you did is good but know you will need to implement all of the event by yourself and this means a lot of work...

Comment: This code is not working currently and I don't know why, I have added plugin in my html file and tried all the way

Comment: angular `element` is not a jquery object. If you have jquery globally available try `$(element).daterangepicker()` and if that doesn't work try using the selector manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a working snippet (that a close look of how i'm making sure that the jQuery loaded before i call `.daterangepiker`

more few think you miss on the way

1. you forgot to put an empty array after you install the module `app.module('publisher-portal',[])`
2. you didn't warp the element in `$()` statement

```js
(function($){
angular.module('publisher-portal',[]).directive('dateRangePicker', function () {
    return {
         restrict : 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link : function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            $(element).daterangepicker();
         }
    };
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.3.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/assets/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/prettify/prettify.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/daterangepicker-master/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css">
<div ng-app='publisher-portal'>

<input id="e2" type="text" ng-model="mydate" date-range-picker /> 
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks you :) for solution

Comment: +1 - The links for the example was helpful to me in answering: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258201/how-to-localize-jquery-ui-daterangepicker

Answer (score 1):

Check out this pure Angular (no jquery required) date range picker.
https://github.com/tawani/taDateRangePicker

[image]