# How to localize jQuery UI DateRangePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using jQuery UI DateRangePicker ([reference](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/)). 
I would like this daterangepicker available in 3 languages (nl, fr and en).

I will be using a switch statement to set the settings for the calendar.

```
switch(curr_lang) {
        case 'nl':
            moment.locale('nl');
            var daterangepicker = $("#search-vac-daterange").daterangepicker(
                {
                    initialText : 'Selecteer datums',
                    dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
                    datepickerOptions: {
                        minDate: new Date(),
                        startDate: new Date(),
                        maxDate: '+2y'
                    },
                    presetRanges: [{
                        text: 'Vandaag',
                        dateStart: function() { return moment() },
                        dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Volgende 7 dagen',
                        dateStart: function() { return moment() },
                        dateEnd: function() { return moment().add(7, 'days') }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Volgende 30 dagen',
                        dateStart: function() { return moment() },
                        dateEnd: function() { return moment().add(30, 'days') }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Volgende 6 maanden',
                        dateStart: function() { return moment()},
                        dateEnd: function() { return moment().add(6, 'months') }
                    }, {
                        text: 'Volgend jaar',
                        dateStart: function() { return moment() },
                        dateEnd: function() { return moment().add(1,'years') }
                    }]
                }
            );
            break;
}
```

The date appears as

> *18 January 2019 - 17 February 2019*

The locale set with moment is not being picked up, and the result is always in English (default).

**NOTE:** I did not manage to get the minDate and startDate to work with moment(), so if anyone has a clue for this. Please help me out!

Comment: If it's using the `$.ui.datepicker` as a base for the widget, you should be abl;e to localize in the same way. Based on the details from git, *A jQuery UI widget similar to the date range picker used in Google Analytics; supports multiple months, custom preset ranges and smart positioning; ThemeRoller-ready and mobile-friendly.* It does not state it supports it natively.

Comment: I think, once you have initialized daterangepicker, you would then need to address the datepicker object and set the regional defaults. Will need to test it.

Comment: @Twisty thanks for the answer! How do I figure out the base of the widget ?

Comment: I am still working on it. I think you just want to `.extend()` the `datePickerOptions` with the return object from `$.datepicker.regional[]`. Two ways to do this, one in initialization and one post init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I would advise is the following example:

```
var cl = "en";
$(function() {
  var drp = $("#search-vac-daterange").daterangepicker({
    datepickerOptions: $.extend({
      minDate: new Date(),
      startDate: new Date(),
      maxDate: '+2y'
    }, $.datepicker.regional[cl])
  });
  var cdrp = drp.data("comiseoDaterangepicker");
  console.log(drp, cdrp);
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/c5db9rng/20/

So this adds the localization. If we review the steps in the DatePicker example, they advise doing the following:

```
$( selector ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

Or:

```
$( selector ).datepicker( "option", $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

> Each localization is contained within its own file with the language code appended to the name, e.g., `jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js` for French. The desired localization file should be included after the main datepicker code. Each localization file adds its options to the set of available localizations and automatically applies them as defaults for all instances. Localization files can be found at https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n.

So that is also important to be aware of. So for your code, I would advise the following.

```
$(function() {
  switch (curr_lang) {
    case 'nl':
      moment.locale('nl');
      var daterangepicker = $("#search-vac-daterange").daterangepicker({
        initialText: 'Selecteer datums',
        dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
        datepickerOptions: $.extend({
          minDate: new Date(),
          startDate: new Date(),
          maxDate: '+2y'
        }, $.datepicker.regional[curr_lang]),
        presetRanges: [{
          text: 'Vandaag',
          dateStart: function() {
            return moment()
          },
          dateEnd: function() {
            return moment()
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Volgende 7 dagen',
          dateStart: function() {
            return moment()
          },
          dateEnd: function() {
            return moment().add(7, 'days')
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Volgende 30 dagen',
          dateStart: function() {
            return moment()
          },
          dateEnd: function() {
            return moment().add(30, 'days')
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Volgende 6 maanden',
          dateStart: function() {
            return moment()
          },
          dateEnd: function() {
            return moment().add(6, 'months')
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Volgend jaar',
          dateStart: function() {
            return moment()
          },
          dateEnd: function() {
            return moment().add(1, 'years')
          }
        }]
      });
      break;
  }
});
```

Semi-Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/c5db9rng/24/

The example does not have the language file, so it's not going to give the proper results, but the code works as expected.

I hope that helps.